# Observable with primeng confirmationservice

Tags: angular, primeng

I need to override a method and add a specific confirmation before it returns Observable. But the confirmation service does not wait for a decision and it does not provide any direct way how to do this. It has some Observables (requireConfirmation$ and accept), but I was unable to use them.

This does not wait for a decision and calls super.aMethod() immediatelly (as expected):

```
aMethod(): Observable {
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
       message: 'A question',
       accept: () => acceptAction(),
       reject: () => rejectAction()
    });
    return super.aMethod();
}
```

This works but it's really ugly and in fact it removes the Observable:

```
aMethod(): Observable {
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
       message: 'A question',
       accept: () => {
                    acceptAction(); 
                    super.aMethod().subscribe(() => {})
                    },
       reject: () => {
                    rejectAction(); 
                    super.aMethod().subscribe(() => {})
                    }
    });
    return EMPTY;
}
```

Any ideas how to do this in a good way?

Answer (score 1):

I found a nicer solution (please, ignore duplications):

```
aMethod(): Observable {
    const subject = new Subject();
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
       message: 'A question',
       accept: () => {
                    acceptAction(); 
                    subject.pipe(concatMapTo(super.save(close)));
                    subject.next();
                    subject.complete();
                    },
       reject: () => {
                    rejectAction(); 
                    subject.pipe(concatMapTo(super.save(close)));
                    subject.next();
                    subject.complete();
                    }
    });
    return subject.asObservable();
}
```